# Why is the Alphafold PAE (predicted aligned error) not symmetric?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, proteins, machine-learning, biomaterials

Cross-posted on [AI Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/37669/19524).

---

We are running alphafold2 multimer on Google Colab to predict the association between two proteins.

It generally works fine, but we get an asymmetric PAE plot for a specific pair. Does anyone know why this might happen? I assumed these must always be symmetrical.

I have provided a figure below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Predicted alignment error is not always symmetric. [This page](https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/faq) from the European Bioinformatics Institute says:

> "`predicted_aligned_error`: The PAE value of the residue pair, rounded to the closest integer. For the PAE value at position (i, j), i is the residue on which the structure is aligned, j is the residue on which the error is predicted."

So if when aligning on residue `i` we get a bad prediction at residue `j`, but when aligning on residue  `j` we get a good prediction at residue `i`, then the PAE plot will be asymmetric.

Below I present two PAE plots from [this website by Tom Goddard (5 April 2022) hosted by UCSF](https://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimerax/data/pae-apr2022/pae.html). The first one looks quite symmetric at first, but I did find some subtle asymmetries, which I've boxed with a red outline:

[image]

The second one is more obviously asymmetric:

[image]